# Asus G75VX / Xubuntu 13.10 EFI installation Blank Screen

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, uefi

I am trying to install Xubuntu 13.10 on a G75VX laptop which has Windows 8 Pre-Installed. So my installation has to be in EFI mode. I've had Xubuntu 13.10 installed in it for a while on a different hard drive and it worked just fine. When i try to install in EFI mode it boots but I get a blank screen after booting. Adding nomodeset to grub like I've done to install in legacy mode will not resolve the issue.

This installation will have the following:

EFI boot.Cannot install Legacy mode due to Pre-installed Windows 8
Ubuntu will be installed on a secondary HDD by itself Along with Windows 8 on Primary HDD.
Nvidia Graphics GTX670MX.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot the installer in legacy (aka CSM or BIOS) mode? If you can, then you can:

1. Install Linux in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.
2. In Windows, install my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)
3. Edit the `refind.conf` file: Uncomment the `scanfor` line and ensure that `hdbios` is among the options.

The result should be that rEFInd will appear when you reboot, and it will give you at least two boot options: One for Windows and one with a gray diamond icon that will boot to the BIOS-mode GRUB, and from there to Linux. You can also add an EFI filesystem driver for ext4fs (or whatever filesystem holds your Linux kernel) to experiment with direct EFI-mode booting. If you can eventually get this to work (because of kernel upgrades or whatever special kernel options overcome the problem), you can switch to a direct EFI-mode boot of Linux.